# Google Calendar API Event Guest getGuestStatus() Not Returning if Guest is Owner

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-calendar-api

Using the Calendar API in Apps Scripts, when calling the [getGuestStatus()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-guest#getGuestStatus()) on a calendar event guest, ["OWNER"](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/guest-status) never seems to be returned. This is consistent when either creating events through the API or adding directly through the GUI. All guests & rooms are accounted for in when calling getGuestList(true) (although there seems to be some differences between the 'organizer' & 'owner' of an event?). Here is an example snippet:

```js
  var testCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("TEST-EMAIL")
  var events = testCalendar.getEvents(new Date("2021-7-17"), new Date("2021-7-27"))
  var guestList = events[0].getGuestList(true)
  for (var i = 0; i < guestList.length; i++){
    Logger.log("Guest: " + guestList[i].getEmail() + ", Status: " + guestList[i].getGuestStatus())
    if(guestList[i].getGuestStatus() == "OWNER") {
      Logger.log("Is owner.")
    }
  }
```

I thought maybe I'm making a wrong check in the IF() block but I can success with other status' such as "YES" or "INVITED". The [other APIs](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events#resource-representations) seem to have a boolean for this but for now I would like to stay within the Apps Script environment.